# Why are my res layout files not showing when I search for them in Android Studio?

Tags: navigation, android-studio

[image]

I'm doing a Ctrl+comma search to navigate/search for a file name in Android Studio. The problem is, it's not finding any xml files, even though I have xml files checked in the class search options. Is there a way to add the res files to my Ctrl+comma search? It finds other non-xml files successfully. I have Visual Studio shortcuts setup for Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Visual Studio default commands, use Ctrl+Shift+N instead of Ctrl+Comma. I wanted to navigate to a File instead of navigating to a Class.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+Space to show Options

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything...I'm also using Visual Studio defaults, so not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: VS keyboard shortcuts, that is